# Where are my uploads going?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, upload

I have some ModalPopUpExtenders on my site where admins can upload videos, documents, images, and pictures to a specific product. The upload seems to work just fine, it shows up in the database and on the site.....but when I click the link on the page it says "The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Nothing is being uploaded into the actual uploads folder that is part of my ASP.net 4.0 VB site. Can anyone tell me what is going on?

```
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="DocumentButton" runat="server">Document</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:Panel ID="DocumentPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display:none">
       Title:<asp:TextBox ID="DocumentTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:FileUpload ID="DocumentUpload" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="SubmitDocument" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="SubmitDocument_Click" /><asp:Button ID="CancelDocument" runat="server" Text="Cancel" /><asp:HiddenField ID="filename" runat="server" />
            </asp:Panel>       
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="DocumentModal" runat="server" DropShadow="True" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="DocumentPanel" TargetControlID="DocumentButton"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
</li>    

    Protected Sub SubmitDocument_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitDocument.Click
    DocumentModal.Hide()
    'Builds the full absolute URL to be inserted into the database. 
    Dim hostURL As String = Request.Url.Scheme & "://" & Request.Url.Host & ":" & Request.Url.Port & Request.ApplicationPath
    Dim sqlFileHREF As String = "INSERT INTO Marketing (ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) VALUES (" & ProductID.Value & " ,4, '" & DocumentTitle.Text & "', '" & hostURL & "uploads/" & ProductID.Value & "/" & DocumentUpload.FileName & "')"
    sqlFileHREF.Replace("'", "''")
    If DocumentUpload.HasFile Then
        Try
            DocumentUpload.SaveAs("uploads" & _
               DocumentUpload.FileName)
            DocumentLabel.Text = "File name: " & _
               DocumentUpload.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
               "File Size: " & _
               DocumentUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength & " kb<br>" & _
               "Content type: " & _
               DocumentUpload.PostedFile.ContentType
        Catch ex As Exception
            DocumentLabel.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
        End Try
    Else
        DocumentLabel.Text = "You have not specified a file."
    End If

    'Create SQL Connection
    Dim SqlConnection As New SqlConnection("Server=off-db1;uid=productsDB_admin;pwd=******;database=Products")
    SqlConnection.Open()
    Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand(sqlFileHREF, SqlConnection)
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SqlConnection.Close()
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify where to save the file:

```
DocumentUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/path/" & DocumentUpload.PostedFile.FileName))
```

Where Server.MapPath will map a virtual path to a physical path, which is what .SaveAs requires.

Comment: I replaced the first statement in the Try to the statement you have but it is still giving me a 404 error. When I hover over the list items, it looks like they have saved to a folder, but it's still not saving.

Comment: My mistake, I took out that entire try/catch and use JUST the code you typed. I replaced /path/ with /uploads/ and it worked. I can see the document in my Solution Explorer, except that my site wants to pull from that product's individual folder. Will I have to make folders for every product's uploads or can I write something to have this application generate a folder for each product. There are 519 products right now

Comment: Oh and thanks by the way! I don't know how long it would've taken me to find an answer on Google :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told the server where to save the file.  Please look at the MSDN walk-through for specific code samples:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx.

Comment: Does it matter where I put the code? I tried it and it still didn't work. I know sometimes things have to be in order to be processed. Please check edits to see what I did.

Answer (score 0):

If no path is specified they are probably in C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: I didn't find them in there. :(